# VSCode IntelliSense can't see things loaded with webpack providePlugin

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm using Webpack [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) to automatically load most commonly used function:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    myFunc: ['app/common.js', 'myFunc'],
}),
```

Now, I can access `myFunc()` everywhere in the project, without need of importing it explicitly.

The problem is, IntelliSense have no idea what `myFunc` is. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.d.ts` typings declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) to tell VS Code that a function called `myFunc` exists in the global scope.

In the top level of your project, create a file called `global.d.ts` with the contents:

```
declare function abc(): void;
```

Also make sure your project has a simple [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson) so that both the `d.ts` file and the `js` files are considered part of the same project

Comment: When I do that, VSCode tries to auto import like this: `import { myFunc } from "./globals";` Which is incorrect, as there is no `globals.js` file. Do you have a fix for this? (besides disabling auto import?)